# Sum of rows till previous row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple rows and columns. I want to create a new column with the minimum values of all rows before the current row. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The minimum of all previous rows can be found using `.cummin()`

```
s = pd.Series([4, 3, 5, 2, 6])
s.cummin()
```

outputs:

```
0    4
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cummin()` function (cumulative minimum) on desired column:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
np.random.seed(7)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,10), columns=['numbers'])
df['cum_min'] = df.numbers.cummin()
df['shifted'] = [df.cum_min.values[0], *df.cum_min.values[:-1]]
df
    numbers cum_min shifted
0   5       5       5
1   7       5       5 
2   4       4       5
3   4       4       4
4   8       4       4
5   8       4       4
6   8       4       4
7   9       4       4
8   9       4       4
9   8       4       4
```

Comment: No, I mean the minimum of all rows till the previous row. The current row must not be included.

Comment: I fixed it, try now.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Is there a way to index the column by its name? And not the column number?

Comment: You can use the `.loc` function instead.

Comment: If I simply replace .iloc in your code with .loc and change the column number to the column name, I get all NaN values in the result.

Comment: In your case when selecting a subset of the column using `.loc` wasn't the best choise. Pleas look at the updated answer, where I've used Series (extracted by passing column name, as you wanted) and slice notation.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand what the * operator does here. Do you mind explaining?